# Open cart product description doesn't show on order email

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

How can I display the product description in order email or admin order history in opencart? Since, I have only very short product description and I made the size as description instead. eg. 20x20kg. I have tried adding to controller:

```
'description' => '$products['description']';
```

and view on order. tpl, but it doesn't show anything.

I added to model like this:

```
'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product['descript‌​ion'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
```

or

```
'description' => htmlspecialchars_decode($product['description'])
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work when I tried to echo it.

VIEW catalog > view > theme > (mytheme) > template > mail > order.tpl

link: http://pastebin.com/zpcWyzsU

MODEL catalog > model > checkout > order.php

link: pastebin.com/37w7ix1Z

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work at all and I cannot find any single article on the net and there isn't any available oc extension. Thinking to create modules/xml instead but not very keen. I would appreciate for someone who could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'description' => '$products['description']'; should be

```
'description' => $products['description'];
```

Comment: Hi Pritam, Thank u for your comment. I just had a typo here. Ofcourse, variable doesn't wrap with single or double quotes. Sorry, if this question is confusing and I need to rectify: controller is like this: 'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_description_length')),  view is like this: <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?> html code here <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($product['description']); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! After a long hours of analyzing the problem. I came up with the solution and I tweaked the codes in catalog > model > checkout > orders.php